C#. Как ограничить количество элементов в массиве char(есть ли более оптимизированный способ)?
Если я ввожу массив вот так:
char[] charArray = new char[11];
charArray = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();

Я могу ввести строку больше диапазона и она её запомнит добавив новые элементы.
В том же C++20 вводя строку через cin она запомнит только первые 10 символов(если столько нет, то запомнит столько сколько есть). Как сделать также в C#?
char[] charArray = new char[11];

Я думал, что добавив = new char[11] я ограничу размер массива, а получилось совсем другое(если все элемента массива не будут заполнены, то выдаст ошибка).
Я сделал вот такую рабочую функцию, но хочу узнать есть ли более оптимизированный способ.
char[] charArray = CharRaz(10);
char[] CharRaz(int razmer)
{
    char[] charArray = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
    if (charArray.Length <= razmer) return charArray;
    charArray = String.Concat<char>(charArray).Substring(0, razmer).ToCharArray();
    return charArray;
}

Есть ли более оптимизированный способ(использовать переменные string нельзя)?

input.CopyTo(0, charArray, 0, Math.Min(input.Length, charArray.Length)), где input это просто var input = Console.ReadLine();.  Ну а если речь про ваш код, то тут лучше использовать Array.Resize(), достраивая тем самым массив до нужного размера.

"string нельзя" - Console.ReadLine() возвращает как раз string.

@user7860670 1. "переменные string нельзя". 2. Там Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();, а не Console.ReadLine(). Оно возвращает значение string(которое в дальнейшем разбивается по элементам массива char), а не переменную string.

это ничем не отличается от ситуации, когда с этим значением string между вызовами ассоциируется какое-то имя. var str = Console.ReadLine(); var charArray str.ToCharArray();

А можно поинтересоваться, с какой целью такое ограничение вводится? И почему string нельзя? Вы же по факту всё равно вызываете ToCharArray() передавая ему string, который вернул ReadLine().

Console.ReadLine().Take(10).ToArray() - не?

@AlexanderPetrov это проглотит лишние символы, а ТС наверное этого не хочет.

@VladD а как понимать "проглотит лишние символы"? В каких случаях это происходит?

@ЛучшийШиномантаж Ну в случае если юзер введет больше 11 символов

@VladD На Visual Studio с этим всё нормально. Берёт столько сколько указано в Take. Может проблема с лишними символами возникает на онлайн компиляторах?

Проблема в том, что если юзер указал больше символов, вы потеряете остаток. Если это нормально, то хорошо.

Ну вот например полностью контроллируемый ввод с филтрацией управляющих символов на базе Console.ReadKey().
private static char[] ReadChars(int length)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[length];
    ConsoleKey key;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        key = keyInfo.Key;

        if (key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && i > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\b \b");
            i--;
        }
        else if (!char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
        {
            Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
            buffer[i++] = keyInfo.KeyChar;
        }
    } while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter && i < length);
    Console.WriteLine();
    return buffer[..i];
}

Проверяем
char[] chars = ReadChars(11);
Console.WriteLine(chars.Length);
Console.WriteLine(new string(chars));

Вывод в консоль
hello world
11
hello world

Если ввести 11, то Enter жать не нужно
А вот если ввести меньше и нажать Enter
hello
5
hello

Backspace работает как в ReadLine().

А почему бы не просто прочитать 11 символов из Console.In? Заодно будет работать даже если ввод перенаправлен.

@VladD потому что оттуда ещё всякие char.IsControl = true могут идти

Ну так мы ж эмулируем C++, читаем из stdin, разве это не то что хочет ТС? По идее там не должно быть контрольных символов типа бэкспейса (если ввод с клавиатуры).

Хотя я не знаю, как в C++ работает с \n в случае, если введено меньше 11 символов. Надо пробовать :)

@VladD ну я сильно не упарывался, у меня был готовый метод для ввода пароля звёздочками в консоли, я 3 строчки переписал и выложил :)

Можно использовать не ReadLine(), а Read(), в цикле до нужного количества, и каждый введенный символ добавлять в массив по индексу.
Так символы будут поочередно записываться, не будет создания новой строки, не будет лишних преобразований.
К тому же количество элементов может и не достигать максимальной длины массива, если добавить символ, по которому запись прекратится.
В случае ниже ввод прекратится после нажатия Enter, но вводить можно сколько угодно.
P.S. Работоспособен код только в Visual Studio для Windows, в остальном под вопросом.
int n = 11;
char temp;
char[] charArray = new char[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  temp = (char)Console.Read();
  if(temp == '\n') break;
  charArray[i] = temp;
}



Если нажать Backspace, всё сломается, и 11 символов будет не ввести.

@aepot, только что проверил и ничего не ломается, все правильно стирается и после этого правильно записывается в массив, из-за чего вы решили что что-то должно сломаться?

С того что ваш цикл не умеет делать i-- если бэкспейс нажать и выполнится ровно 11 раз.

Хм, интересно. В Visual Studio все работает правильно, в онлайн компиляторе на onlinegdb - нет. Но пока у меня нет мыслей почему так происходит. В любом случае, в Visual Studio мой код отлично работает и я не соврал. Ну и если вы знаете, было бы очень интересно узнать

Я же написал, что не так. При удалении символа в консоли, индекс в массиве тоже должен сместиться влево.

Нет, это я уже понял. Я о том, почему мой код работает в VS включая Backspace и не работает в других местах. Как я понял дело в консоли Windows, но чем она отличается?

Вероятно это может зависеть от кодировки консоли, надо тестировать.

Разница в том, что в консоли бэкспейс обрабатывается самой консолью и не попадает в stdin. А при вводе в онлайн-отладчиках ввод идёт через перенаправление из файла, и никто не обрабатывает спецсимволы.
